# Typo in Definition of Orthogonal Set of Vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, inner-products, orthogonality

The following is definition C.7 from Appendix C (Linear Spaces Review) of *Introduction to Laplace Transforms and Fourier Series, Second Edition*, by Phil Dyke:

[image]

Shouldn't that be $1 \le i, j \le n$? Is it a typo?

And, of course, the $a_r \not= 0$ should be typeset to $\mathbf{a}_r \not= 0$?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand your first point. And it seems that these really are two typos.

Comment: @whereamI That's fine. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so that the question can be marked as answered:

As has already been clarified in the comments, these are both errors.

Comment: How do I community wiki answer?

Comment: @ThePointer: When you answer a question, there's a checkbox labeled "community wiki" near the bottom right of the input text area.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks.

Comment: It says that I must still wait 2 days before accepting the answer.

Comment: @ThePointer: That's weird, because for me it's already showing the answer as accepted.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to my (now-deleted) community wiki answer. I misunderstood what you were requesting.

Comment: @ThePointer: Ah, a fatal chain of misunderstandings :-) I should have checked the timestamp. So, all cleared up now.